# Чтение файла с float32 значениями

Tags: python, файлы, float, ansi

вопрос такой : как понять, что прога правильно считывает файл? открывается только в кодировкe ANSI, если выбрать любую другую, то вылетает

```
` with open(fileName1, "r", encoding='ANSI') as f:
     data = f.read()
  data = np.array(data)
  data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='float32')`
```

Comment: Убери скриншоты и положи кодом в тело вопроса.

Comment: Вылетает с какой ошибкой?

Answer (score 0):

Если данные в файле хранятся в двоичном формате, то и открывать его нужно соответственно:

```
with open(fileName1, "rb") as f:
     data = f.read()
```

Ну а конкретно в этом случае тогда можно вот так:

```
data = np.fromfile(fileName1, dtype='float32')
```